# Modeling and executing a 1 to n collaboration in BPMN

Tags: bpmn, camunda, bpmn.io, camunda-modeler

**Given**

I have the following BPMN process (collaboration), where three actors are involved. Two of them (Actor 1 and Actor 3) represent a **single** instance. While Actor 2 represents **n** instances (open the image in new tab to enlarge).

[image]

**Background**

The basic idea is that Actor 1 initiates a task, which should make ALL instances of Actor 2 create data and send it back to Actor 1. In the end Actor 1's activity collect results should collect all the data of all Actor 2 instances.

**Question**

My question is: Is this even possible and executable to model in one monolithic diagram (while the engine execution manages the instances part), or should I split this into two processes, using signal events?

In the literature, the multi-instance participant (here Actor 2) is usually marked with three vertical lines, but I am not sure, if the engine supports this.

Is there otherwise a better approach to model a 1 to n relation?

**Note:** I am still learning BPMN, tell me if I am totally in the wrong here. Thanks a lot.